# puppet only exec when file does NOT exist

Tags: puppet

I only want to exec following command when file (/usr/local/bin/papply) does not exist.  not sure what to put there.

```
    exec { 'git add url':
        command =>'git remote add origin https://github.com/testing/puppet.git',
        require => Exec['git init'],
        cwd => '/home/vagrant/django',
        user => 'vagrant',
        onlyif => "not sure what to put here"
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
onlyif => "test ! -f /usr/local/bin/papply"
```

Not sure if Puppet can use the '!' character

Perhaps a better alternaltive:

```
creates => '/usr/local/bin/papply'
```

even if i don't like the fact that the command doesn't really creates the file

Comment: not working, got this error message.   Could not evaluate: Could not find command '!'

Comment: And this: onlyif => "test ! -f /usr/local/bin/papply"

Comment: creates => '/usr/local/bin/papply'  works, thank you.  let me test your updates, see if htat one works.

Comment: onlyif => "test ! -f /usr/local/bin/papply" works, also the one I prefer to use. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on linux just do

```
unless => 'ls /somefile'
```

ls will return with a non-zero return code if the file does not exist and unless will only let the exec it is under execute if its test returns a non-zero return code.

Answer (score 2):

On linux and puppet >3.8 try:

```
exec { 'test':
   command => '/bin/echo HI',
   unless  => 'test -f /a/file.txt',
}
```

exec will not run if `/a/file.txt` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [creates](https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/run-exec-if-file-absent.html), which exists for this purpose:

```
exec { 'git add url':
  command => 'git remote add origin https://github.com/testing/puppet.git',
  creates => '/usr/local/bin/papply'
}
```